# The method '_ScreenState' isn't defined for the type 'Scanscreen'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method

Tags: android, flutter, dart, github

So I have been working on a flutter app right now. I have the feature that requires permission from the camera and gallery to pick and capture images. So  I watched some tutorials and I copied the same process, use the plugin image_picker. But before that, I already have the plugin permission handler which is default from Dhiwise. Now, There is this error that I encountered while trying to insert the code that will let the app replace the default image to the captured/picked image.

Here is the code for the scan screen.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'controller/scan_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:grabbitapp/core/app_export.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Scanscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Scanscreen({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<Scanscreen> createState() => _ScanScreenState();
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class ScanScreen extends GetWidget<ScanController> {
  File? image;

  Future pickImage() async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

      if (image == null) return;

      final imageTemp = File(image.path);

      setState(() => this.image = imageTemp);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Failed to pick image: $e');
    }
  }

  Future pickImageC() async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

      if (image == null) return;

      final imageTemp = File(image.path);

      setState(() => this.image = imageTemp);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Failed to pick image: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
            body: Container(
                width: size.width,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Container(
                        decoration:
                            BoxDecoration(color: ColorConstant.whiteA700),
                        child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              image != null
                                  ? Image.file(image!)
                                  : Text("No image selected"),
                              Container(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: getHorizontalSize(10.00),
                                      top: getVerticalSize(135.00),
                                      right: getHorizontalSize(10.00)),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: ColorConstant.bluegray100,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                          getHorizontalSize(15.00))),
                                  child: Column(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: getHorizontalSize(5.00),
                                                top: getVerticalSize(50.00)),
                                            child: Image.asset(
                                                ImageConstant.imgRabbitdflt,
                                                height: getVerticalSize(236.00),
                                                width:
                                                    getHorizontalSize(320.00),
                                                fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                                        GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              onTapImgCameraicon();
                                            },
                                            child: Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: getHorizontalSize(
                                                        10.00),
                                                    top: getVerticalSize(43.00),
                                                    right: getHorizontalSize(
                                                        10.00),
                                                    bottom:
                                                        getVerticalSize(27.29)),
                                                child: Image.asset(
                                                    ImageConstant.imgCameraicon,
                                                    height:
                                                        getVerticalSize(77.71),
                                                    width: getHorizontalSize(
                                                        82.93),
                                                    fit: BoxFit.fill)))
                                      ])),
                              Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: getHorizontalSize(10.00),
                                      top: getVerticalSize(135.10),
                                      right: getHorizontalSize(10.00),
                                      bottom: getVerticalSize(20.00)),
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        onTapBtnNext();
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          height: getVerticalSize(40.60),
                                          width: getHorizontalSize(267.48),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: ColorConstant.amber400,
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(
                                                      getHorizontalSize(20.30)),
                                              boxShadow: [
                                                BoxShadow(
                                                    color: ColorConstant
                                                        .black9003f,
                                                    spreadRadius:
                                                        getHorizontalSize(2.00),
                                                    blurRadius:
                                                        getHorizontalSize(2.00),
                                                    offset: Offset(6, 6))
                                              ]),
                                          child: Text("lbl_next".tr,
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              style: AppStyle
                                                  .textstylemontserratromanmedium201
                                                  .copyWith(
                                                      fontSize: getFontSize(20),
                                                      letterSpacing: 1.20)))))
                            ]))))));
  }

  onTapImgCameraicon() async {
    await PermissionManager.askForPermission(Permission.camera);
    await PermissionManager.askForPermission(Permission.storage);
    List<String?>? imageList = [];
//TODO: Permission - use imageList for using selected images
    await FileManager().showModelSheetForImage(getImages: (value) async {
      imageList = value;
    });
  }

  onTapBtnNext() {
    Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.rabbitGeneratedInfoScreen);
  }
}
```

The error is this,

The method '_ScanScreenState' isn't defined for the type 'Scanscreen'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '_ScanScreenState'.dartundefined_method

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using GetX for your application, so you don't have to use stateful widget. You can remove the below code from your file as there is two Class with the same name.

Remove this code:

```
class Scanscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Scanscreen({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<Scanscreen> createState() => _ScanScreenState();
}
```